# Not keyword vs = False when checking for false boolean condition

Tags: vb.net

When I'm using an If statement and I want to check if a boolean is false should I use the "Not" keyword or just = false, like so

```
If (Not myboolean) then
```

vs

```
If (myboolean = False) then
```

Which is better practice and more readable?

Comment: I was using ``(myboolean = False)`` but SonarCube identified it as a Code Smell:  Code Smell (minor): Remove the unnecessary Boolean literal(s).  I changed it to the ``(Not myboolean)`` I realize this is a very old question but I was searching to make sure I had the correct vb.net syntax and came across it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Definitely, use "Not".  And for the alternately, use "If (myboolean)" instead of "If (myboolean = true)"

The works best if you give the boolean a readable name:

```
 if (node.HasChildren)
```

Comment: You'll never convince me that something like   Not txtbox.WordWrap is more readable than txtbox.Wordwrap = False.

Comment: @dwidel I actually find them exactly the same. Although in non-BASIC languages it's a different story. `if (txtbox.WordWrap == false)` is indeed much more readable than `if (!(txtbox.WordWrap))`. What bothers me is performances, because it makes sense there's a difference. One of them evaluates one Boolean, then evaluates another one (`== false`), and the other is evaluating a Boolean, and transforms it. I'll have to check.

Comment: I think it depends on how you name your variables and what you are used to.  For example, if I see `(!HasChildredn)` in C# I interpret that as doesn't have children.  When I see `(Not HasChildren)` in VB.NET  I am obviously forced to see "Not HasChildren" which of course could look confusing.  All preference in my opinion

Answer (score 7):

Since there's no functional difference between either style, this is one of those things that just comes down to personal preference.

If you're working on a codebase where a standard has already been set, then stick to that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `True` and `False` to *set* variables, not to test them.  This improves readability as described in the other answers, but it also improves portability, particularly when best practices aren't followed.

Some languages allow you to interchange `bool` and integer types.  Consider the contrived example:

```
int differentInts(int i, int j)
{
   return i-j;  // Returns non-zero (true) if ints are different.
}

. . .
if (differentInts(4, 8) == TRUE)
   printf("Four and Eight are different!\n");
else
   printf("Four and Eight are equal!\n");
```

Horrible style, but I've seen worse sneak into production.  On *other* people's watches, of course.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the consensus, when there is both a true case and a false case please use

```
if (condition)
    // true case
else
    // false case
```

rather than

```
if (not condition)
    // false case
else
    // true case
```

(But then I am never sure if python's `x is not None` is the true-case or the false case.)

Comment: IMO it depends. I prefer to put the more common case first, if the difference is large. For example: if(it_works) ... else ...  and if(not error) ... else ...

Comment: Yes, that very much depends. For example, you usually want to have error cases out of the way as soon as possible, i.e. you put them ahead.

Comment: This is great in theory, but doesn't really help when you only need to do something when the variable is false.

Answer (score 1):

! condition

In C and pre-STL C++, "!condition" means condition evaluates to a false truth value, whereas "condition == FALSE" meant that the value of condition had to equal what the system designed as FALSE.  Since different implementations defined it in different ways, it was deemed better practice to use !condition.

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comment -- FALSE is always 0, it's TRUE that can be dangerous.

Comment: The false value in C has never been anything but 0.

Comment: Right now that I think of it,  it's TRUE that's a problem

Comment: In other languages, there can be more values that evaluate to false, like Perl and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use "Not", consider reading it aloud.

If you read aloud:

If X is false Then Do Y
  Do Y

Versus

If Not X Then Do Y

I think you'll find the "Not" route is more natural.  Especially if you pick good variable names or functions.

Code Complete has some good rules on variable names.  http://cc2e.com/Page.aspx?hid=225 (login is probably required)

Comment: I respectfully disagree - nobody I know of speaks in that way, and when I read code I'm doing exactly that, reading it out loud (but silently - unless it's a real WTF)

Comment: That's fair.  Although I think ultimately when I read something, I mentally read it aloud ... I guess I prefer graphical, then audio, then text, and that approximates it.  Could also explain why I read abysmally slow!

Comment: I'd have to disagree too, "If myFlag is false" reads more naturally than "if not myflag". I'm not sure that means I would favour = false over not, because I'm more used to if (!myflag)...

Comment: @endian It's probably people who took Boolean logic classes that use `Not`, because of all the `Not P And Q` stuff. And also people who are used to assembly language, because you would negate a Boolean before a compare and jump, rather than checking if a value equals a constant for True or False.

Answer (score 1):

Something else: Omit the parentheses, they’re redundant in VB and as such, constitute syntactic garbage.

Also, I'm slightly bothered by how many people argue by giving technical examples in other languages that simply *do not apply* in VB. In VB, the only reasons to use `If Not x`  instead of `If x = False` is readability and logic. Not that you’d need other reasons.

Completely different reasons apply in C(++), true. Even more true due to the existence of frameworks that really handle this differently. But *misleading* in the context of VB!

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any difference as long you are dealing with VB only, however if you happen to  use C functions such as the Win32 API, definitely do not use "NOT" just "==False" when testing for false, but when testing for true do not use "==True" instead use "if(function())".

The reason for that is the difference between C and VB in how boolean is defined.

1. In C true == 1 while in VB true == -1 (therefore you should not compare the output of a C function to true, as you are trying to compare -1 to 1)
2. Not in Vb is a bitwise NOT (equal to C's ~ operator not the ! operator), and thus it negates each bit, and as a result negating 1 (true in C) will result in a non zero value which is true, NOT only works on VB true which is -1 (which in bit format is all one's according to the two's complement rule [111111111]) and negating all bits [0000000000] equals zero.

For a better understanding see my answer on [Is there a VB.net equivalent for C#'s ! operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279208/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator/17580187#17580187)

Answer (score 0):

Made a difference with these lines in vb 2010/12
With the top line, Option Strict had to be turned off.

```
If InStr(strLine, "=") = False Then _
If Not CBool(InStr(strLine, "=")) Then
```

Thanks for answering the question for me. (I'm learning)