# Is there a VB.net equivalent for C#'s ! operator?

Tags: vb.net

After two years of C#, I'm now back to VB.net because of my current job. In C#, I can do a short hand testing for null or false value on a string variable like this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blah))
{
   ...code goes here
}
```

however I'm a little confused about how to do this in VB.net.

```
if Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(blah) then
   ...code goes here
end if
```

Does the above statement mean if the string is not null or empty? Is the `Not` keyword operate like the C#'s `!` operator?

Answer (score 14):

In the context you show, the VB `Not` keyword is indeed the equivalent of the C# `!` operator. But note that the VB `Not` keyword is actually overloaded to represent two C# equivalents:

- logical negation: `!`
- bitwise complement: `~`

For example, the following two lines are equivalent:

- C#: `useThis &= ~doNotUse;`
- VB: `useThis = useThis And (Not doNotUse)`

Answer (score 10):

Yes they are the same

Comment: They act the same way, but they're definitely not the same. 'Not' in VB is overloaded to represent both logical negation and bitwise complement.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I have not used bitwise complement operators in vb.net or C#

Answer (score 7):

`Not` is exactly like `!` (in the context of `Boolean`. See RoadWarrior's remark for its semantics as one's complement in bit arithmetic). There's a special case in combination with the `Is` operator to test for reference equality:

```
If Not x Is Nothing Then ' … '
' is the same as '
If x IsNot Nothing Then ' … '
```

is equivalent to C#'s

```
if (x != null) // or, rather, to be precise:
if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
```

Here, usage of `IsNot` is preferred. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for `TypeOf` tests.

Answer (score 2):

They work identically until you reference C or C++ code.

For example doing NOT on the result of a Win32 API function, might lead to incorrect result, since true in C == 1, and a bitwise NOT on 1 does not equal false.

```
As 1 is        00000000001
Bitwise Not    11111111110
While false is 00000000000
```

However in VB it works just fine, as in VB true == -1

```
As -1 is       11111111111
Bitwise Not    00000000000
```

Comment: Just to clarify the above answer, in VB there is no == operator; only the = operator.  So in VB true = -1 and in C true == 1.

Comment: I don't know the reason why VB uses -1 but I guess that it is because the VB `NOT` operator is a bitwise not, so in order for false (which is 0) to be `NOT True` they had to defined True as -1

Answer (score 0):

c# : boolean example1 = false;

```
 boolean example2 = !example1;
```

vb.net: dim example1 as boolean = False

```
    dim example2 as boolean = Not example1
```

Answer (score -1):

Seconded.  They work identically.  Both reverse the logical meaning of the expression following the !/not operator.

Comment: They act in the same way, but they're definitely not the same. 'Not' in VB is overloaded to represent both logical negation and bitwise complement.