# What is Visual Basic's equivalant to Java's "!"?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know Visual Basic's equivalant to Java's "!"

Example of how it would work in Java:

```
If !code.DoesExist {
    log.info("This code doesn't exist!");
} 
 Else {
    log.info("This code does exist");
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

In my code I need to do the following:

```
            If imgUrl.Contains("imgur") Then
                ImagesFound += 1
                Select Case ImagesFound
                    Case 1
                        imgBox.ImageLocation = imgUrl
                End Select
            ElseIf !imgUrl.Contains("") Then
                '<some code here>
            End If
```

I need it at the 7th line.

Note: I can't just use "Else" I need to specifically point out that if an image with imgur in the HTML source wasn't found, then this and that should happen.

Comment: Use Not operator as pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279208/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per suggestion, here is more elaborated answer :

**Not** Keyword : Performs logical negation on a Boolean expression, or bitwise negation on a numeric expression.

For more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx

**<>** : Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not; if values are not equal, then condition becomes true.

For more info : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_operators.htm

Comment: `Not` and `<>` are used in different contexts.  Elaborating on your answer to explain their usage might make for a better answer.